# When trying to install a package I get "npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app"

Tags: npm

When trying to install a package I get
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app

Comment: Include all error messages.

Comment: You might also try [searching on Stack Overflow for similar symptom of "npm ERR! 400 Bad Request"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=npm+ERR%21+400+Bad+Request&mixed=0)

Comment: (apparently, OP cross-posted from https://stackoverflow.com/q/57151113/2821954)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I resolved (this worked when I was working locally) by removing all the other lines in .npmrc and only leaving:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

The per-user config file (.npmrc) is found in you your home directory :

```
cd ~/
```